# Error from catch is not returned in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created the next function that should return the `response`, `data` and `error` in case if exists.

```js
const login = function(cb) {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => {
      cb(null, null, response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      cb(data, null, null);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('error inside catch:', e.message)
      cb(null, null, e)
    })
}

console.log(login((data, response, err) => console.log('data', data, 'response', response, 'error', err)))
```

So, I have to return all these values, but I can return just `data`. If I change this: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` to this: `https://j123sonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`, to return `err`, I get `undefined`. The same issue is with response.
Question: How to get all these values?

Comment: I copied your Code to a jsfiddle and it logs 'error inside catch' when supplying a nonexistent url. If there is an error, there is no data.

Comment: @ccarstens how to get all these data in ` console.log('data', data,'response', response, 'error',err))`?

Comment: Your callback has three arguments but you call it always with just the first. hence, whatever you pass to the callback ends up as `data`. try `cb(null, null, errorObject)` to pass an error

Comment: @ccarstens, i changed the code above, but why i don't get the response in the console.log()?

Answer (score 3):

```
// you write
cb(response);
cb(data);
cb(error);

// so the data and error below make no sense
cb(response, data, error)
```

You passed 3 params to the `cb` when using it in `console.log`. But in the `login` function declaration, `cb` accepts only 1 param.
That means your `console.log` always prints 2 times, the first is the Response of API call and the second is the data (if success - then) or error (if fail - catch).

```
const arr = []
const login = function (cb) {
    // const arr = []; move array inside login function if not use outside
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => {
        arr[0] = response;
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        arr[1] = data;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        arr[2] = e;
      })
      .finally(() => {
        cb(...arr);
      });
  };

login((response, data, err) => console.log('response', response, 'data', data, 'error', err))
// console.log(arr[0]) // response
// console.log(arr[1]) // data
// console.log(arr[2]) // error
```

Comment: i changed the code above, but why i don't get the response in the console.log(). Why? ow to solve?

Comment: Don't do that, It will always run 2 times with unexpected behavior. Wait for me 1 min I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: i got you, but how to return and `data` and `response`? I understand that i make 2 renders, but how to get both values? Thanks. Could you please add this feature in your anseer?

Comment: could you help?

Comment: but how to get data in console? For example i want to get `data` and `response`, how to do this?

Comment: You can get the array of [response, data, error] by use the `cb`.

Comment: Check the code again, I've updated, it can be more comprehensible.